# C++ safe object deletion

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, delete-operator

I'm writing a relatively big project in C++ and have a problem with object deletion. The project, to be precise is a roguelike game.

I have a class `Npc` which is every monster in the game. They are created and stored in a separate class, `Storage<Npc>`, that is responsible for their management (loading, saving, creation, deletion, etc). Whenever a monster dies, corresponding object `npc` has to be deleted and destroyed completely. It is not a problem to delete object itself, I just have invoke a method from `Storage<NPC>`. The problem is that code contains a lot of pointers to this already-dead `npc`, which are now invalid and trying to use them will cause a lot of issues. For example:

1. There may be an action he intended to perform before he died.
2. Tile on which he stood record store a pointer to him.
3. He may have been involved in some continuous activities, like grappling somebody.

There are a lot of such pointers in the code, so it is nearly impossible to simply track them. What I need is some way to determine that an `npc` is already dead, and there is no actual object stored on that address, so that parts of code which still have this pointer can adequately react to his death.

I myself have come up with several ideas, but so far none of them seems really good to me:

- I could ask `Storage<NPC>` class if it has an object on such address. The potential problem is that after object deletion, another object may be allocated on the same address, which will cause bugs.
- I could notify all locations that could possibly use the invalid pointer. It is a bad idea because number of such locations will increase over time and doing this is a pain.
- I could implement some version of smart pointer, but I'm unsure on which one to use.

**tl;dr version**: I need a solution that will tell me if a pointer points to an object, or it points to a free chunk of memory, or to some other object, allocated after original object deletion.

Comment: How about setting it to `nullptr` every time the memory is freed/becomes invalid? :P

Comment: You already tagged your question with an answer: Use smart pointers. I suggest using std::shared_ptr

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, I guess what you're trying to say is that whenever I do `delete pnpc;` I should do `pnpc = 0;`. But if there is another pointer equal to `pnpc` is stored somewhere else in the program it will not be set t 0, so I guess that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using weak pointers? If you store the `Npc` in a `std::shared_ptr` (C++11, use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` for C++03), you can then create `std::weak_ptr`s (C++11 again, use `std::tr1::weak_ptr` for C++03) that refer to the `shared_ptr`. When the `shared_ptr` actually deletes its object, then all the `weak_ptr`s will be able to figure this out.

Although I have to wonder why you're deleting `Npc`s that are still being used elsewhere (e.g. that still have actions). If instead of trying to have all these other references discover you've deleted the `Npc`, you just want the `Npc` to die once all references disappear, then using a `shared_ptr` by itself (with no `weak_ptr`) will work correctly.

Comment: I want to use the approach I described because that's how game mechanics work. An NPC can die at any moment, and it makes perfect sense that he cannot perform actions or be a part of the map anymore. I don't want any meaningful code to be executed after NPC's death and one way to ensure that is to delete corresponding object immediately after his death.

Comment: @Saage: I would think that if an Npc dies then you would proactively remove its animations and remove its presence on the map before deleting the Npc (or possibly as part of its destruction, although that may be a bad idea), instead of relying on the map and actions list to realize later that the Npc is gone. This way you can do things like query the action list for its size and be assured that's actually the count of pending actions.

Answer (score 3):

With the information you provided, what I can suggest is you implement the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
If there is code that needs to react to the NPC's death, this pattern is the way to go. Code sections having pointer references to your NPC will be notified upon NPC death and null their copy of pointer to NPC and react to the NPC's death however required. The death notification is sent to all `observers` before the NPC is actually deleted.

With this pattern, you could implement mechanics such as "Hero gains 50 HP for each monster killed", and it's easily scalable.

You can also use Kevin Ballard's suggestion of using `shared_ptr` if no code needs to actively react to the NPC's death, and just needs to handle the case where the NPC is dead.

Comment: I guess I'll end up using `shared_ptr` because it sounds simpler, but Observer pattern is a great idea and I'll definitely find it useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to include a reference count in your class. When some other object (a room, for example) is going to hold a pointer to an npc, the room has the responsibility of increasing the npc's reference count. Now, instead of just deleting a dead npc, you flag it as dead (through another new data member if you don't already have the right flag), and only delete if its reference count is zero. The room object also has the responsibility of periodically checking that flag and if it learns the npc is dead, it decrements its reference count (which will cause a post mortem deletion, if the count is now zero).